# Is it possible to specify a row component in react-table or react-bootstrap-table?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table, react-table

I'm in the process of migration a lot of tables in my project from simple HTML tables ,styled with bootstrap 4, to a more sophisticated solution, like the ones offered by `react-table` or `react-bootstrap-table`.

The problem is that from what I've seen in this components,if you want to customize the contents of a row and let's say, specify a "Details" button for each row, you have to do it via a Column component (using a Cell reference).

> **react-bootstrap-table:** https://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/example.html#column-format
>
> **react-table:** https://github.com/react-tools/react-table#custom-cell-header-and-footer-rendering

What I want to know is whether it is possible to create a component that centralizes the rendering of a whole a row (e.g. `<TableRow />` ) ?

If this is possible, the migration will be a lot easier.

Also I'm asking about these two libraries, because I find them both easy to use, quite mature and with the features I look for in a table component. So if one of the has what I need, I'll definitely pick that library over the other.